# Retrieve Class of ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, class-method

Given the following simplified models, I need to return an empty QuerySet of a ManyToManyField, but I receive an 
*"AttributeError: 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'none'"*

```
class AnimalFamily(models.Model):
  objects = GetOrNoneManager()
  siblings = objects.none()


class Countable(models.Model):
  @classmethod
  def get_peers(cls_obj,target_animal):
    animals = cls_obj.objects.get_or_none(siblings=target_animal)
    if animals:
      return animals.siblings.exclude(id=target_animal.id)
    else
      return cls_obj.siblings.none()    # <--- this fails <----

  class Meta:
    abstract = True


class BearFamily(AnimalFamily,Countable):
  siblings = models.ManyToManyField(Bear)

class GiraffeFamily(AnimalFamily,Countable):
  siblings = models.ManyToManyField(Giraffe)


class Bear(models.Model):
  pass

class Giraffe(models.Model):
  pass
```

How can I get access to the "Bear"-Class or the respective "Giraffe"-Class in the generic classmethod to return an empty query of the correct QuerySet?

Extra info:

```
# dir(cls_obj.siblings) returns:
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__set__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'field', 'related_manager_cls', 'through']
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message clearly points to the problem saying that the object you are returning has no attribute named "none". This is probably what you want:

```
if animals:
  return animals.siblings.exclude(id=target_animal.id)
else
  cls_obj.siblings = []   
  return cls_obj.siblings
```

Comment: Sadly this does not help, because I am not looking for an empty queryset or empty list of cls_obj (which would be an empty queryset of BearFamily), but rather of an empty queryset of the Class which is referenced in the ManyToMany field (i.e. empty Bear or Giraffe queryset). I know that these exist, because  'Bear.objects.none()' does return an empty queryset. Bear is another django class (I'll add that to my code-example to make it even clearer)

Comment: OK, if I am understanding this correctly, you are trying to define a queryset as empty if there are no animals in the query that match the target animal. I that case, you don't need to set an empty query set in the base class (AnimalFamily), but move that operation into the child. In that case, your base class definition would look like this: class AnimalFamily(models.Model):
  #objects = GetOrNoneManager() you are adding to confusion by using a django method name as a class attribute
  siblings = objects.none()

Comment: class AnimalFamily(models.Model):
  siblings = GetOrNoneManager.objects.all()                                           That way the line that fails later will be syntactically correct. Sorry for all the formatting issues  - still getting used to posting here.